# File share subscriptions of single report with large size

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report that is more then 25MB when rendered.

However, it’s not possible to add a File Share subscription, as the size of report is to big. I get:

> Error: Maximum request length exceeded.

When I looked around for a solution on the internet, I found an option to change a web.config parameter:

```xml
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="9000"  maxRequestLength="allowed value"/>
```

That can be changed to allow for bigger size. I changed the parameter, but it did not resolve the issue.

Could any one please help? Perhaps if I could use parameters to make the report smaller and run multiple subscriptions to generate reports for them? How can I do this? Please help me by providing some solutions/links.

Comment: Actually, **maxRequestLength** is for the size of the RDL file  - the report definition file not the resulting report with data. 
When are you getting the error? In the **Status** of the Report **Subscriptions**?

Comment: When I'm trying to create a file share subscription. As soon as I choose, file share, I got this error.

Comment: There are actually two different settings with the same name. Unfortunately, our environment is locked down so I can't see how ours is set. Check out http://www.bidn.com/blogs/MikeMollenhour/ssis/248/reporting-services-2008-error-maximum-request-length-exceeded - that looks like your same issue.
"If you change the web config file in **ReportManager** and **not ReportServer** your report will work" -  
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/31a74097-28cc-4f29-9397-fdeda1cca994/maximum-request-length-exceeded-help

Comment: As per above link, i have modified web.config file here, still no help.  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER2\Reporting Services\ReportManager  , Can any one please help?